# using svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin with storybook

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, sprite, storybook

I'm trying to use the `svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin` package with Storybook.

Here's the `./.storybook/webpack.config.js` file I'm using to setup the plugin in the `preview webpack config` following the docs best practice : https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#full-control-mode

```js
const SVGSpritemapPlugin = require('svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
  config.plugins.push(new SVGSpritemapPlugin(path.join(__dirname, '../assets/icons/*.svg')))
  return config
}
```

By adding `console.log(...)`s to the `svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin` source, I'm sure that my svg files are read, and the spritemap is generated in memory. But I can't find the generated spritemap after startin storybook.
By using `--debug-webpack` I could confirm that output path exists.

Does anyone have an idea how to generate a spritemap using storybook webpack config ?

EDIT : I made a minimal storybook project to demonstrate the issue : https://github.com/romaindurand/storybook-svgspritemap/

Comment: I am having the very same issue now - did you find out how to do it in the end?

Comment: @Johnwilliams unfortunately no. I had to write a custom js script using the `svg-sprite` npm package
:(

Comment: Yea i did something similar in the end